# Predicting Future With FBProphet

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet, prophet

I have been using fbprophet to make a time series prediction. I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I have tried to do a future prediction using the following code and want to predict 30 years in the future:

```
p_model = Prophet()

df_plot = df_grouped.copy()
df_plot = df_plot.reset_index()
total_vehicles = df_plot.groupby(['year'])['all_motor_vehicles_miles'].sum()
total_vehicles = total_vehicles.reset_index()
total_vehicles['total_miles'] = total_vehicles['all_motor_vehicles_miles'] * 365

total_vehicles[['y', 'ds']] = total_vehicles[['total_miles', 'year']]

p_model.fit(total_vehicles)
future = p_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=30, freq='Y')
forecast = p_model.predict(future)
forecast.head()
```

However, when plotting this, prophet has predicted in the past rather than the future from 2020 to 2050 below and I'm not sure why?

[image]

Anyone know why this is the case and how to fix it? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues was with my date not being in the right datetime format. Simply making sure the type was right and then putting it into prophet yielded the right answer.

```
total_vehicles['year'] = pd.to_datetime(total_vehicles['year'], format='%Y')
```

[image]